# import * as iterable array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

**How can I access multiple classes in different files, as array, using TypeScript?**

folder structure:

```
├── index.ts
└── models
    ├── index.ts
    ├── image.entity.ts
    └── user.entity.ts
```

image.entity.ts:

```
export class Image { }
```

user.entity.ts:

```
export class User { }
```

models/index.ts:

```
export * from './image.entity';
export * from './user.entity';
```

index.ts (desired output):

```
import * as models from './models/index';
// Is an iterable array, instead of a "module"
console.log(models.length) // 2
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you'd expect, i.e. what do you want `models` to look like?

Comment: @Tao `models` should be the TypeScript type:  `(typeof Image | typeof User)[]`.

Maybe I should expand;
The framework I'm currently using, TypeORM, requires for its ORM an array of entities. The connection object of TypeORM looks like:
{ host: '0.0.0.0', ..., entities: [Image, User] }. Because I don't want to manually expand the `entitites`-array, everytime I add a new model, I want to use the TypeScript `import` functionality, if possible, or any other way.

Comment: sorry, I hadn't read the part "desired output" and was a little confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you have it, you could iterate over `models` simply with one of `Object.keys`, `Object.values` or `Object.entries`. Note that you'll need to add `es2017` to `--lib` for the latter two to work.

If you really want `models` to be an array you could do it like this:

image.entity.ts

```
export default class Image { }
```

user.entity.ts

```
export default class User { }
```

index.ts

```
import Image from './image.entity';
import User from './user.entity';

export default [
  Image,
  User,
]
```

and then import it like this:

```
import models from './models';

console.log(models.length) // 2
```

Note that you don't need to use deault imports/exports but they will save you some `* as x`.